# Change php variable from jquery value using ajax (same page)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What I'm trying to do it simply this:

I've a php global variable `$currentID` and with a simple jquery script I check if there is a "id" (page) in the hash of url and if yes I wanted to give that value to `$currentID`.
I've been reading a lot and I notice that I shall use Ajax but I'm not managing it.

My code now is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   if (parent.location.hash != '' ) {
     var theCurrentID = parent.location.hash.split('#')[1];
      $.ajax({
            url: 'my.php', //current page
            type: 'post',
            data: {theID: theCurrentID },
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function () {

            }
        });
   }
  // your code here
});
</script>
```

Could you help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot change a server side variable client side! PHP is a server side scripting language so once it is processed and sent to the browser, no changes can be made to PHP variables. However, using ajax, you can extract data from a PHP page and update your HTML document where necessary.

Comment: PHP is processed server side. Once the htm is rendered, you cannot modify a 'embeded' php variable unless you reload the page. That's said, you can set a js variable set by a php variable.

Comment: @user2389750 clear your requirement : do u want to get data from server ,or set data to server through ajax !!!

Comment: thank you both, I'll try to give a look on your advices.

Comment: Niladri Das, I just want to be able to modify a php variable using a jquery value, in the same page, without reloading.

Comment: @user2389750 You cannot do this because the variable does not exist client side!!!!!

Comment: @user2389750 So you need to set a javascript variable using a php value and then updating this js variable using ajax

Comment: @user2389750 When your php script has finished processing and the output is sent to the browser, there are no more php variables as your php script has terminated. So there is nothing to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP is a server side language, meaning that once it has sent its data to the browser, the PHP variables and data cannot be changed...

However, using AJAX, you can send another request to a PHP page and change data in the DOM based on the result.

Consider this:

```
var id = parent.location.hash.split('#')[1];;

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.net/id.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {id: id},
    success: function(data){
        // Do whatever you want with you JSON object
        // The following will log what has been returned
        console.log(data);
        // If you want to update your id variable then simply do this
        id = data.id;
        // You can then change elements in the DOM that reflect what your PHP
        // variable originally set
        $('#id').text(id);
    }
});
```

The following will include the `$currentID` as it was sent when the page loaded... But, you can update this text using the above script.

```
<p>My current ID is: <span id="id">$currentID</span></p>
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** This will not update the PHP variable as once PHP has sent data to the browser, the script has terminated and it cannot be modified, nor can varibles be accessed. The above script will simply update the text in the HTML.

### Server Side Scripting

You need to understand how server side scripting functions before you start programing PHP, it is pretty basic really:

1. You send a request to `my.php`
2. This request goes to the server where PHP generates your HTML, it will write any variables you have specified into the HTML
3. The data is then sent back **as HTML**, **NOT PHP**, to the browser, where you can use javascript to make changes to the DOM.

The bottom line is, once PHP has generated and sent your page data to the browser, nothing to do with PHP then exists on that page! It is pure HTML, or whatever other type of document it may be...

Another way to explain it is this:

Your **server** sees the PHP page as this:

```
echo "<p>My current ID is: <span id=\"id\">$currentID</span></p>";
```

Your **browser** (where javascript sees it), sees the page like this

```
<p>My current ID is: <span id="id">1</span></p>
```

There is no PHP variable to access, it simply does not exist!

See the following for more information:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: Does not exist anywhere anymore...

Comment: Thanks Ben!

So there's no way to get the value of id and update the value of the $currentID variable value to the id?

Comment: @user2389750 You need to understand how server side scripting works. The PHP script is executed on the SERVER, and then the resulting data, which does not contain any PHP varibles, only text, will be sent to the browser (client side). `$currentID` does not exist once the page has been generated! I will try and explain it better in my answer

Comment: @user2389750 You are missing the point, there is no `$currentID` variable after the script has finished / the page has loaded.

Comment: @jeroen See my update, I have tried to explain in the simplest terms possible how server side scripting works. Feel free to add to it :-)

Comment: Ben, that you for your patience. I got the ideia. 

But now I'm even more sad. Ahrrg. 

Thank you!

Comment: @user2389750 There is never a need to change PHP data client side, you can use javascript to change anything in the document you would like to, so dont be sad. Turn that frown upside down :-) Javascript is awesome!!

Comment: Yeah, but in this particular case it would be really usefull to me to just change the value of the php variable.

Comment: Just to finish the post:

What I'm trying to do is this:

if the link entered is, per example, "www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php#subpage5" I want to save "subpage5" to a variable so I can use it to load respective content from mysql database (I'm doing it with php.)

if the link entered is "www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php" I want to set the subpage0 was the one to be shown.


> With the page already loaded, I've a left side menu where I have all subpages names linked respectively to href="subpageIndex" - everything is being loaded from mysql with php as well.

Comment: To finish, I've a click event to thoses left side menu bar links. So, when I click on them the content of my div is uploaded. (Now I'm doing it by reload the page but I think that I cant to it without reloading with AJAX, right? )